# what is '@' means in scheme language?

Tags: lambda, scheme

I am trying to understand the following function:

```
((lambda 'b
((lambda 'a '''''a) 'b `(this)))
(lambda (x)
(lambda (z)
`(,x ,@z)))
(car ''unquote))
```

the output is:

```
(quote quote quote quote quote this)
```

I am trying to understand the `'@z'` meaning, someone knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `'`  is [syntax-sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for [quote](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quote.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._quote%29%29)

#### `` ` ``  is syntax-sugar for [quasiquote](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._quasiquote%29%29)

#### `,`  is syntax-sugar for [unquote](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._unquote%29%29)

#### `,@` is syntax-sugar for [unquote-splicing](https://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall00/ai/scheme/reference/schintro-v14/schintro_129.html#SEC182)

---

Look at this simple example:

```lisp
`(1 ,(+ 1 1) ,@(list 3 4)) ;==> (1 2 3 4)
```

You can rewrite it like this and you will get the same result:

```lisp
(quasiquote (1 (unquote (+ 1 1)) (unquote-splicing (list 3 4)))) ;==> (1 2 3 4)
```

---

https://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall00/ai/scheme/reference/schintro-v14/schintro_129.html

https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/04wi/lectures/14-scheme-quote.html